# Decrease the space between two type of footnotes

Tags: spacing, footnotes, footmisc

I’m using two types of footnotes in my document, but when I use the two types in the same page, the space between the two blocks is too large (the paper size small, so it is problematic). Is there a way to reduce the space between the two blocks of notes? My minimal example working is

```
\documentclass[twoside,book]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[perpage,multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage[xetex,
    papersize={138mm,215mm},
    total={115mm,180mm}]{geometry}

\paragraphfootnotes 
\renewcommand*{\footnoterule}{}
\footmarkstyle{\textbf{#1--} }
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{0ex}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{1em}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\Alph{footnote}}

\newfootnoteseries{G}
\plainfootstyle{G}
\footmarkstyleG{\textbf{#1--}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1]{}\footnote{Short footnote}

\lipsum*[2]{}\footnote{Another short footnote}

\lipsum*[4]{}\footnoteG{\lipsum*[3]{}}

\lipsum[5]\lipsum[6]{}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to get rid of all space between the two levels of footnotes?  LaTeX fights pretty hard to keep some space there.  I think this is pretty wise, in fact.  In your case, there are two things you could do to get rid of *some* excess vertical space:

```
\setlength{\footskip}{0pt} 
\setlength{\footnotesep}{0pt}
```

Also, given that you defined a footnote series 'G', you could do something like this:

```
\newskip\supersmallskipamount 
\supersmallskipamount=1pt plus 1pt minus 1pt
\skip\footinsG=\supersmallskipamount% <-- see memoir.cls, starting where 'newfootnoteseries' is defined
```

Try putting `\the\footskip` and `\the\footnotesep` in your first two footnotes then try compiling with the two `\setlength`s (not) commented out.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It appears the the `\setlength{\footskip}{0pt}` line decreased the space between the end of the footnote and the footer; `\setlength{\footnotesep}{0pt}` indeed decreased the space between the two block of notes in the way I intended, but not all of it, as is supposed to. Unfortunatelly, that also decreased the space between two or more G series (the numbered ones) notes, so it looks kind of odd. I suspect that some lenghts related to the footnote rule could decrease the space without that effect. Do you know which ones are involved?

Comment: The second block of code only works when only are G series footnotes. Sorry for my english; I hope that it were understandable.

Comment: @marlonob -- yes, very true.  If you had defined an 'H' series, you would need to do the same with `\footinsG`.  Or you could re-define the long `\newfootnoteseries` command from `memoir.cls`.  I chose this route because it made a shorter answer.  If you like I can add how you would want to re-define `\newfootnoteseries`.